# Compile time warning when using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close'

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, ambiguity

Anyone know how to solve this warning message?

> Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close(ref object, ref object, ref object)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentEvents2_Event.Close'. Using method group.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The only way I've managed to resolve the warning is to use an explicit cast:

```cs
var doc_close = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document) _doc;
doc_close.Close();
```

If you already have a `using` for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` you can simplify the cast to:

```cs
var doc_close = (_Document) _doc;
doc_close.Close();
```

or even just

```cs
((_Document)_doc).Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of visual studio, you can add this line to the top of the source file to remove the ambiguity.

```
using Document = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
```