# Warning CS0467 when using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close'

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

The problem (C# compiler warning message):

> warning CS0467: Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.close(ref object, ref object, ref object)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentEvents2_Event.Close'. Using method group.

The (partial..) solution:
[Compile time warning when using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640594/ambiguity-between-method-microsoft-office-interop-word-document-close)

The dilemma:
If I explicitly cast to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document`, ReSharper warns me that the "Type cast is redundant"

The question:
Is there a real solution for this warning message, not just patchwork?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just don't cast, C# doesn't require it:

```
Word._Application app = new Word.Application();
Word._Document doc = app.Documents.Add(...);
doc.Close(...);    // No ambiguity
app.Quit(...);
```

Comment: Got the warning CS0467 when I was using Word.Application and Word.Document - both without the starting _. Just adding the _ as your solutions shows solved the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you need casting to avoid error... Cast !

Resharper has (good) generic rules, but sometimes they can't be applied.

You can "hide" the resharper warning message in this specific case ("Suppress inspection xxx with comment"), or... live with (if you can / are allowed to).

EDIT : ok, got the warning with lib version 12.0.0.0

So you can try

```
_Document w = new Document();
```

and you shall avoid c# and resharper warning.

Comment: Well..I'm doing a lot of code refactoring and I can not afford to "hide" any message :) If I was allowed, I would suppress directly the CS0467 Warning message from the very beginning.

Comment: could you give a little bit more code (at least "usings" and problematic code), version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word lib and version of Visual Studio, I can't reproduce on VS 2010 with lib version 14.0.0.0

Comment: Microsoft Office.Interop.Word version 12.0.0.0, Visual Studio 2010 SP1
Microsoft Office.Interop.Word w = ...;
w.Close(...); //compiler warning

Comment: Hmmm, look at my edit, it could help, but the code you give doesn't help much (I don't think w is of type Office.Interop.Word). If it doesn't help, more code is needed...

Comment: I check once again the code and it's like this:
Document w = ...;
If I go to the declaration of "Document" type, it sends me to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace which has a public interface Document : _Document, DocumentEvents2_Event.

Comment: change Document w to _Document w as in my edit. The Close ambiguity is in fact an interface inheritance problem.