# C# ambiguity error on Document.Close() when converting VBA macro to C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

The Word VBA macro that I am converting to C# has the following line.
I am very specifically using the `Close()` method on the `Document` object. I have not found any question that exactly answers my question below. There are *similar* questions, such as this one: [Compile time warning when using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640594/compile-time-warning-when-using-microsoft-office-interop-word-document-close)

But looking at it I was not able to figure out the exact cast I have to use.

```
ActiveDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

I converted this to C# like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word.Document oWordDoc = new Word.Document();

oWordDoc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, oMissing, oMissing);
```

However at the last line I get the following ambiguity error:

> Ambiguity between method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.Close(ref object, ref object,
>   ref object)' and non-method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentEvents2_Event.Close'. Using
>   method group.

Obviously I can't rename the `Close` method of Word (I guess), so I tried to cast my `oWordDoc` but nothing seems to work.

Can someone shed some light on it how to do this right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document`, which does not contain that event.

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)oWordDoc).Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDo‌​NotSaveChanges, oMissing, oMissing);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this: `(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)oWordDoc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, oMissing, oMissing);` But it gives a compiler error: **"Cannot convert type 'void' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document'"**

Comment: @nikhilvartak Please either leave a comment with a suggestion asking SLaks to include the change, or post it as your answer - You shouldn't be editing in solutions to other answers (even though you are trying to help, and it's likely correct!)

Comment: @ib11 You should be casting like this: `((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)oWordDoc).Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDo‌​NotSaveChanges, oMissing, oMissing);` @Rob thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @nikhilvartak --  Well, I don't say new to you if I say: "it works" Dah... Thanks a lot!

Comment: It linked in automatically this related post, though it is not a duplicate, but I put it here so it is linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303969/how-to-eliminate-warning-about-ambiguity